# how to use Authorize with @inherits?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

c# with a blazor application

I'm using Microsoft Identity Web to get the scopes from my Azure AD. This is working and I can use

```
[Authorize(Policy = "GroupAll")]
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] {Constants.ScopeUserRead})]
```

This is working fine but now I want to create 2 pages with page 1 a different policy then page 2. And page 2 is using @inherits to reuse 99% of the code of page 1.

How do I do this? because the [authorize] code is before the
public partial class classname : ComponentBase

I hope my problem is clear. Sorry im still learning.

Maurice

Comment: Not sure it's worth an interim base class to replicate one or two lines of code? Especially as the first instance needs a different policy -- unless I've misunderstood the question. Just add the code to each page and change the policy. Copy-paste-edit is fine for such a small set of code.

Comment: question is not clear, please provide more code.